# insert error in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I wrote the code bellow ! I guess I am having problem in connecting to db ! right? I cant insert data into database ! where is the problem? how can I solve it?

Here's example:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    String uname = jTextField1.getText();
    String pass =  jTextField2.getText();
    String fname = jTextField3.getText();
    String lname = jTextField4.getText();
    String gender = (String) COMBOgender.getSelectedItem();
    String address = jTextArea1.getText();
    String email = jTextField5.getText(); 
    try
    {

    //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEREN","root","");
    Statement stat = con.createStatement();

    String insert = "insert into tbl_User (username,password,firstname,surname,gender,address,mail_address) VALUES ('"+uname+"','"+pass+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+gender+"','"+address+"','"+email+"')";

    stat.executeUpdate(insert);
    //stat.close();
    //con.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserted Successfully!");

    }
    catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error occurred in inserting data");
    }

    ;// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: any errors you are getting?

Comment: remove comments from Class.forName() and close statements

Comment: call   con.commit() after executeupdate

Comment: Do `e.printStackTrace()` inside `catch()` block and paste that error in above post.

Comment: and please use PreparedStatement. The way you create the insert sql is not secure!

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEREN

Comment: @JerenAkhoundi have you included mysql.jar in your build path.Additionally which IDE you are using?

Comment: Remove the comment from `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` as told by @BhavikShah and add a `catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)`

Comment: Yes I have MySQL(connector/J driver) under Drivers. I am using netbeans

Comment: @AJ. doing that gives me this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: @JerenAkhoundi I think you might not have included the correct mysql.jar

Comment: @JerenAkhoundi download this mysql.jar from this site http://www.javaskool.com/jardownload/jarfiles/mysql.jar and let me know if you get errors or not?

Comment: I did .. but still have problem .. please see the image : http://www.uploadax.com/images/12082484688561266938.png

Comment: THANK YOUUUU EVERY BODY IT WORKKKKKSSSSS <3

Answer (score 0):

Download MySQL java driver from here.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Extract the archive and get the .jar file. In NetBeans IDE, goto project explorer window, right click on libraries under your project name, and select Add Jar/Folder. Select the .jar file you just extracted.

Then, modify your code as follows.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEREN","root","");
Statement stat = con.createStatement();

...

stat.close();
con.close();
```